# How to change year end in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

I have a matrix with column 1 as `YEARMONTH (202001, 202002, ....)`

Column 2 is SALES.

In the matrix currently the value for `Jan to Dec 2020` gets summed for `year 2020.`

I want to have year to have months only from `April to March`. Example `2019 is` `Apr 2019 to Mar 2020`. `2020 is Apr 2020 to Mar 2021.`

How can I implement this in power bi?

Answer (score 2):

Try with below:

Fiscal year

***1. Create a FiscalYearNumber  column as***

```
FiscalYearNumber=If( Month([Date]) >= 7  , Year([Date]),Year([Date]) -1 )

FiscalYearDisplay = ="FY"&Right(Format([FiscalYearNumber],"0#"),2)&"-"&Right(Format([FiscalYearNumber]+1,"0#"),2)
```

***2) Create a column called FiscalMonth***

```
FiscalMonth=(If( Month([Date]) >= 7  , Month([Date]) - 6,Month([Date]) + 6 )
```

***3) Create Fisical Quater***

```
FiscalQuarterNumber =  ROUNDUP ([FiscalMonth]/3,0)

FiscalQuarterDisplay= "FQ" & format([FiscalQuarterNumber],"0")
```

Comment: If you satisfied with my answer, please mark vote

Comment: After creating these formulas do I have to pull them all into visualization?

Comment: Yes. In the Visualization you can select above created column as per your need